# How to pass user's choice using AutoCompleteTextView in Android app?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am building an app in Xamarin and I've got a AutoCompleteTextView to give users multiple choises after they start typing text. It works but for some reason I am not able to save the choise in string and pass through to next function.

```
    string choise;

    void InitializeAutocomplete() {
        var autoCompleteOptions = new String[] { "hello", "see you" };
        ArrayAdapter autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line, autoCompleteOptions);

        var autoCompleteTextView = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autoComplete);
        autoCompleteTextView.Adapter = autoCompleteAdapter;
        choise = ?!?!
    }
```

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it thanks to [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20805/autocompletetextview-get-selected-item) thread on Xamarin Forum:

Added:

```
void autoTextView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteTextView autoText = (AutoCompleteTextView)sender;
    choise = autoText.Text;
}
```

and

```
void InitializeAutocomplete() {
        var autoCompleteOptions = new String[] { "hello", "see you" };
        ArrayAdapter autoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line, autoCompleteOptions);

        var autoCompleteTextView = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.autoComplete);
        autoCompleteTextView.Adapter = autoCompleteAdapter;
        autoCompleteTextView.ItemClick += autoTextView_ItemClick;
    }
```

Now variable choise returns the user choise.